# Как создать уведомление в xamarin forms/android которое будет напоминать уведомление о звонке в IOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Я создаю приложение , в котором у меня есть звонки , в момент когда происходит звонок ,мое приложение показывает уведомление как на картинке ниже

[image: Уведомление]

Проблема заключается в том что уведомление скрывается в шторку самостоятельно , хотя звонок еще идет , а мне надо что бы оно отображалось все время пока идет звонок Например как на Iphone , примерно вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже показан стандартный код построения внешнего вида уведомления , которым я пользуюсь.
Я задумывался о том, как можно продлить время, когда уведомление отображается на экране , но пока не нашел решения(

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
         .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
         .setContentText(subject)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
         .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
         .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел книгу в которой описано , как подменить стандартный шаблон уведомлений на свой, вот название книги.
Matthew Leibowitz - Xamarin Mobile Development for Android Cookbook - 2015.

Думаю все знают где скачать книги бесплатно

[Тут я нашел как создать Layout](https://forasoft.com/blog/article/how-to-make-a-custom-android-call-notification-455) , а так же тут объяснили как его внедрить.